# How to export HDFS directory with beeline (no HDFS access)?

Tags: hive, hdfs, beeline

I have access to a hive cluster through beeline. Results of some queries get stored as files in hdfs (e.g. /user/hive/warehouse/project). These results are just lines of texts.

Would it be possible to "download" those files to my local machine only using beeline as I don't have access to hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

You can by

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/your/path/' SELECT your_query
```

Comment: I can't run a query because the results are just text files on HDFS and not hive tables. 
Ideally I would just do `hadoop fs -get /user/hive/warehouse/results` but I don't have access to hdfs so I was looking for a workaround to achieve the same using beeline.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try do something like this.

```
beeline: -e "select * from yourtable" > LOCAL/PATH/your_output
```

I'm runing this command from a unix server on remote HDFS server.

Regards.